# linq2db 3.0.0-preview.1 not working with .net core 3

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, linq2db

linq2db 3.0.0-preview.1 isn't working with .net core 3, showing error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'UdtTypeName' is not a member of type System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter' (Parameter 'propertyOrFieldName')
>   While the same thing works great on .net core 2.2

since the exact same code works in .net core 2.2, the question arises whether it currently works with .net core 3 or will have to wait a while. Regarding the possibility of linq2db working with .net core 3, I really did not find any information, which oddly enough, is unusual.

On github there is a closed problem with a similar error, but it seems that the problem is fixed, and in the code I do not use UdtType, and the error crashes with any action with the database context, even with a simple fetch

Is it possible to somehow make this work or will I have to wait for a new version of linq2db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you use `System.Data.SqlClient` < 4.5.0 as this property was added to `SqlParameter` in this version?

Update: as quick fix you can update dependency to 4.5.0 or higher, but it looks like you've hit preview1 [issue](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/issues/1948)